# Business Card Printing Standards

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

I am currently trying to create my first ever business card. However, I am not sure what are the standard properties which I need to give to my image file. For this project, I am using Photoshop, and here are the settings which I found from different sources over the Internet.

- Width: 3.5 inches
- Height: 2 inches
- Resolution: 762 Pixels/Inch
- Colour Mode: CMYK Colour (8bit)
- Colour Profile: U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2
- Pixel Aspect Ratio: Square Pixels

I would be really grateful if someone who has more experience in this area can verify these settings. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Resolution: 300ppi - and you'll want to include bleeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I work in mm but I am certain the same can apply for inch measurements.

If the final size of my business card is 85mm x 50mm then I add 3mm for bleed (~10% of an inch) , basically what this means is the printer has an area they can cut into so my cards do not have any white on the border edge.

Have look at this image I found on the net, hopefully it illustrates my point well. 
[image: a simple illustration detailing the setup of a card.]

I would advise you to speak to your printer about what their requirements are and create your design around that.

Comment: Definitely consult your printer. Usually printers have similar requirements to one another, but you never know. One of my printers always requests .ai files while another works with PDFs.

Comment: @user239996 Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I just have one more question. Should the borders which are on the sample you showed also be on the business card so it will be easier for the printing studio to cut them?

Comment: @AshleePalka Thank you for the advice. I will do that.

Comment: @GeorgeStoqnov not necessary, as long as you have created your card with the appropriate bleed and safezone or critical margin as the figure above illustrates, just be sure to tell them what your final card size will be, usually my printer sets their own crop marks, but check with yours it might be different.